# How to reduce the frequency of ActiveMQ KeepAlive messages

Tags: activemq-classic

Whe have configured HTTP transport for ActiveMQ.  However, we are noticing that there are thousands of KeepAlive messages.  I understand that KeepAlive messages are used to control how "dead" connections are detected and purged by the Inactivity Monitor: http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-inactivitymonitor.html

```
<org.apache.activemq.command.KeepAliveInfo>
  <commandId>0</commandId>
  <responseRequired>false</responseRequired>
</org.apache.activemq.command.KeepAliveInfo>
```

From the documentation, it seems that Inactivity Monitor can be turned off, but what I am trying to figure out if there is a setting to "reduce" the amount of chatter on a line but not completely eliminate.  I am OK with one message per second, for example, but we are getting thousands.

Answer (score 1):

A transport connector has a paramater "wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration" that determines the maximum inactivity duration.  To reduce the frequency of keepalives, increase this value.  The default value is 30000 (30 seconds).

If the default value of 30 seconds is in practice, and you are getting thousands of keepalives per second, I would expect you have tens-of-thousands of connections.

Here is an example of specifying this paramater:

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="openwire"
        uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=30000&amp;wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

If the other end of the connection specifies a shorter duration than your end, the shorter duration will be used by both ends of the connection.  There doesn't appear to be a setting for a "minumum inactivity duration", so you will have to live with that if a client chooses a very short duration.